# How to create a custom layout/theme for swagger-ui 3.x

Tags: reactjs, swagger-ui

I would like to create a custom theme (and maybe later a layout) for Swagger-ui 3.x. Being unfamiliar with React i have a hard time finding the right starting point. Can anybody point me in the right direction?